# MongoDB, which tier has more than three indexes for atlas search?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

my application needs about 10 indexes in atlas search, but the default/free tier only allows me to create three.
It says: Indexes Used: 3 of 3. You have reached the index limit for your cluster tier.
Now the question is, which tier I should choose, but I can not find which tier allows for how many indexes.

Does somebody know where I can get this information?

Comment: M10 and above should do the trick

Comment: Ok, but for this project, M10 would be overkill and I think it is a bit expensive. Do you know if I it is also possible with M2 or M5 (or whatever the other shared options are called)? Otherwise I will use atlas search on the big collections and mongoose-fuzzy-search for the rest

Comment: The [Free/M2/M5 limitations](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/) don't specify a max number of indexes. However, those tiers do not provide the ability to [build indexes with a rolling build](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo DB has published the limitations here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/limitations/

You cannot create more than:

- 3 indexes on M0 clusters
- 5 indexes on M2 clusters
- 10 indexes on M5 clusters